# Custom Intellij language built on the top of XML

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

First of all, what is my intention. I have a set of XML files in my project. Some of those are hierarchical. The top XML looks like this (very simple example)

```
<RootElement>
  <Element id=1>
  <Element id=2>
  <Element id=3>
<RootElement>
```

The element itself contains some other elements and attributes, but it is not relevant in this case.

Than there are many files with this structure:

```
<RootElement>
  <Element id=1 superId=3>
  <Element id=2 superId=3>
  <Element id=3 superId=2>
<RootElement>
```

Where the superID is index to root XML file. What I want to implement is a plugin which I would use for simple navigation between those two files.

My idea was to create a new language which will extend XML and add some extra functionality. Only files with specific names (2 or 3) will be part of this language.

I have created the new language:

```
public class MyLanguage extends XMLLanguage {

  public static final MyLanguage INSTANCE = new MyLanguage();

  protected MyLanguage() {
      super(XMLLanguage.INSTANCE,"MyLanguage", new String[]{"text/xml"});
  }
}
```

New file type:

```
public class MyLanguageFileType extends XmlLikeFileType {      
  public static   final MyLanguageFileType INSTANCE = new MyLanguageFileType();

protected MyLanguageFileType() {
  super(MyLanguage.INSTANCE);
}
@Override
public Icon getIcon() {
    return Icons.FILE;
}
```

And new factory:

```
public class MyLanguageFileFactory extends XmlFileTypeFactory {
  @Override
  public void createFileTypes(FileTypeConsumer fileTypeConsumer) {
    fileTypeConsumer.consume(MyLanguageFileType.INSTANCE,
            new   FileNameMatcherFactoryImpl().createMatcher("nameOfXML1.xml"),
            new FileNameMatcherFactoryImpl().createMatcher("nameOfXML2.xml")
    );
}
```

What is the first problem? I see files with the right icon, but when I create Anotator and register it to MyLanguage, it doesn't work. When I register the same Annotator to the XML file, annotations works well.

So the first question is, what have I done wrong?

Thanks all.

P.S.: Minimally FileTypeFactory works well because I can see files with specific names with icons I have set to it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to implement your own language to support the navigation. All you need to do is to implement a PsiReferenceContributor that will inject references into the attributes of your XML files.

Comment: Thank you very much, but I have two following question. Is possible to define how will be shown references in popup window in case of more than one result? I can see in my popup window the name of XmlTag which is referenced, but I would like to see value of one attribute belongs to the referenced XmlTag. And second question is, how to suppres "cannot resolve symbel" warning when no reference was found? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Another solution if you just need code completion and static analysis is to use an `<xml.schemaProvider implementation="...">` tag in your `plugin.xml` file with a custom `XmlSchemaProvider` that returns a local `*.xsd` file packaged with your plugin. See [JavaFxSchemaProvider](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/blob/master/plugins/javaFX/src/org/jetbrains/plugins/javaFX/fxml/JavaFxSchemaProvider.java) for an example of how to do this.